# Yii2 remember sort option after submit the searchForm

Tags: forms, sorting, yii2

I use an ActiveForm in Yii2 for my SearchModel. After click on search button the form fields remember previous values but SorterDropdown is refreshed.

```
<?php echo SorterDropdown::widget(['sort' => $dataProvider->sort,
      'label' => $model->sortedBy($dataProvider->sort->attributes),])
?>
```

SorterDropdown is just a wrapper of ButtonDropdown.
How can I forse the SorterDropdown to remember sort order (and show it) after the form submition?

```
class SorterDropdown extends LinkSorter
{
    public $label;
    protected function renderSortLinks()
    {
        $attributes = empty($this->attributes) ? array_keys($this->sort->attributes) : $this->attributes;
        $links = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $name) {
            $links[] = Html::tag('li', $this->sort->link($name, ['tabindex' => '-1']));
        }
        if (empty($this->label))
                $this->label = 'Sort';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown::widget([
                        'encodeLabel' => false,
                        'label' => $this->label,
                        'dropdown' => [
                        'items' => $links,
                        ],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: SorterDropdown ? is it your on widget ? or any open source one ?

Comment: It is a wrapper for ButtonDropdown. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some class to li element, which indicate active state of it and special style in CSS file.